# return observable but wait until another finishes

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I was ask to add a functionnality to a legacy code. The legacy code handle a get request with some added features like avoiding duplciate calls and cache get request when PWA is offline.

In the context of this PWA when have some POST/PUT/DELETE operation I want to commit before any get is executed.
I made an observable $processingOfflineOperation which return true or false and I want to delay any get operation until $processingOfflineOperation next to false.

this is the get method :

```
public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {
    const pendingObs = this.checkIfPendingToAvoidDuplicateCalls('GET ' + endpoint, params);
    if (!!pendingObs) {
      // return duplicate call
      return pendingObs;
    }
    if (!reqOpts) {
      reqOpts = {
        params: new HttpParams()
      };
    }

    let header = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: this.getAuthorizationHeaderValue()});
    header = header.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    reqOpts.headers = header;
    endpoint = (endpoint) ? endpoint : '';
    if (!this.network.online && !avoidCache) {
      // return from cache
      return of(this.cacheCalls['GET ' + endpoint + ' ' + JSON.stringify(params)]);
    } else if (!this.network.online) {
      return throwError(() => new Error('No internet'));
    }
    const $obs = this.http.get(this.url + endpoint + '?' + this.JSON_to_URLEncoded(params), reqOpts).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        this.clearPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params);
        if (!!ignoreHTTPStatusCode && !!ignoreHTTPStatusCode.find((status) => status === err.status)) {
          return of(null);
        }
        this.manageError(err);
        return throwError(err);
      }),
      map(res => {
        this.clearPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params);
        this.addCacheCall('GET ' + endpoint + ' ' + JSON.stringify(params), res);
        return res;
      }),
      share()
    );
    this.setPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params, $obs);
    return $obs;
  }
```

I have no idea how to proceed all my attempt ended changing the behaviour of the get method
My best guess was this but this is not working as excpected :

```
public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {


    const $subject = new Subject();
    this.$processingOfflineOperation.subscribe(isProcessing => {
      if (isProcessing) {
        return ;
      }

      const pendingObs = this.checkIfPendingToAvoidDuplicateCalls('GET ' + endpoint, params);
      if (!!pendingObs) {
        // return duplicate call
        $subject.next(pendingObs);
      }
      if (!reqOpts) {
        reqOpts = {
          params: new HttpParams()
        };
      }

      let header = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: this.getAuthorizationHeaderValue()});
      header = header.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
      reqOpts.headers = header;
      endpoint = (endpoint) ? endpoint : '';
      if (!this.network.online && !avoidCache) {
        // return from cache
        $subject.next(this.cacheCalls['GET ' + endpoint + ' ' + JSON.stringify(params)]);
      } else if (!this.network.online) {
        $subject.error(new Error('No internet'));
        return throwError(() => new Error('No internet'));
      }
      const $obs = this.http.get(this.url + endpoint + '?' + this.JSON_to_URLEncoded(params), reqOpts).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.clearPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params);
          if (!!ignoreHTTPStatusCode && !!ignoreHTTPStatusCode.find((status) => status === err.status)) {
            return of(null);
          }
          this.manageError(err);
          $subject.error(err);
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        map(res => {
          this.clearPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params);
          this.addCacheCall('GET ' + endpoint + ' ' + JSON.stringify(params), res);
          $subject.next(res);
        }),
        share()
      );
      this.setPendingCall('GET ' + endpoint, params, $obs);
      $obs.subscribe();
    });
    return $subject;
  }
```

Following @dmance comment I tried to rename the first version of the get into getReal and created a new function "get" then I did this :

```
  public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {

    return this.getReal(endpoint, params, avoidCache, reqOpts, ignoreHTTPStatusCode).pipe(
  filter(() => !this.isProcessing), 
  take(1)
);
  }
```

but still no chance,
then this :

```
public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {
    const $subject = new Subject();
    this.getReal(endpoint, params, avoidCache, reqOpts, ignoreHTTPStatusCode).pipe(
      skipUntil(this.$processingOfflineOperation.pipe(filter(isProcessing => {
        return isProcessing === false;
      })))
    ).subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        $subject.next(v);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        $subject.error(err);
      }
    });
    return $subject;
  }
```

not working either.

Not sure this is the most elegant way to do it, but this one works :

```
 public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {
    const $subject = new Subject();
    this.$processingOfflineOperation.subscribe((isProcessing) => {
      if (!isProcessing) {
        this.getReal(endpoint, params, avoidCache, reqOpts, ignoreHTTPStatusCode).subscribe({
          next: (v) => {
            $subject.next(v);
          },
          error: (err) => {
            $subject.error(err);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return $subject;
  }
```

Comment: When you call the function that executes the get do before the check, return an observable TRUE/FALSE and filter it in order to execute or not the get.

Comment: @dmance if it's not too much to ask, can you provide an example with just the filter and execute ?

Comment: to block until everything finishes use `forkJoin(arrayOfObservables)`

Comment: as @Antoniossss said... use a forkJoin to put all the pending operations, if any, and then to the GET... I like his approach too... It's better than my first suggestion of only send get if there were not pending requests. You can use an IF to check if there is pending before the get, if is not pending just launch the GET, if not, use a forkJoin and then pipe it with a switchMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure this is the most elegant way to do it, but this one works :

```ts
 public get(endpoint: string, params?: any, avoidCache?: boolean, reqOpts?: any, ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]): Observable<any> {
    const $subject = new Subject();
    this.$processingOfflineOperation.subscribe((isProcessing) => {
      if (!isProcessing) {
        this.getReal(endpoint, params, avoidCache, reqOpts, ignoreHTTPStatusCode).subscribe({
          next: (v) => {
            $subject.next(v);
          },
          error: (err) => {
            $subject.error(err);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return $subject;
  }
```

## Elegant

You should be able to re-write this without an intermediate Subject. I can't test this for you, but something like this should work:

```ts
public get(
  endpoint: string, 
  params?: any, 
  avoidCache?: boolean, 
  reqOpts?: any, 
  ignoreHTTPStatusCode?: HttpStatusCode[]
): Observable<any> {
  return this.$processingOfflineOperation.pipe(

    mergeMap(isProcessing => isProcessing ? EMPTY : 
      this.getReal(endpoint, params, avoidCache, reqOpts, ignoreHTTPStatusCode)
    )

  );
}
```

You'll notice that by not managing your own subscriptions, the code becomes much shorter/concise. In general, nested `subscribe` blocks are a code smell. There's most often a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
forkJoin(pendingOperations)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((_) => yourGetOperation())
  ).subscribe(getResults => console.log(getResults));
```